# How to display the current year in the template of a block?

Tags: theming, blocks, 9

I'm trying to rewrite the "Powered by Drupal" block. I want to display the current year in my code but cale does not work. The website displays a blank page with the message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

This error appears when I add `{{ 'now' | date('Y') }}` in the code.

Here is the block template :

```
{% block content %}
  {{ attach_library('olivero/powered-by-block') }}
  <span>
    {% trans %}Copyright © {{ 'now' | date('Y') }} example.fr - Tous droits réservés{% endtrans %}
    <a href="https://www.example.fr">{% trans %}example.fr{% endtrans %}</a>
    <span class="example-logo" aria-label="{{ 'Example Logo'|t }}">
      <svg width="14" height="19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 42.15 55.08" fill="none" aria-label="{{ 'Drupal Logo'|t }}" role="img">
        <path d="M29.75 11.73C25.87 7.86 22.18 4.16 21.08 0 20 4.16 16.28 7.86 12.4 11.73 6.59 17.54 0 24.12 0 34a21.08 21.08 0 1042.15 0c0-9.88-6.59-16.46-12.4-22.27zM10.84 35.92a14.13 14.13 0 00-1.65 2.62.54.54 0 01-.36.3h-.18c-.47 0-1-.92-1-.92-.14-.22-.27-.45-.4-.69l-.09-.19C5.94 34.25 7 30.28 7 30.28a17.42 17.42 0 012.52-5.41 31.53 31.53 0 012.28-3l1 1 4.72 4.82a.54.54 0 010 .72l-4.93 5.47zm10.48 13.81a7.29 7.29 0 01-5.4-12.14c1.54-1.83 3.42-3.63 5.46-6 2.42 2.58 4 4.35 5.55 6.29a3.08 3.08 0 01.32.48 7.15 7.15 0 011.3 4.12 7.23 7.23 0 01-7.23 7.25zM35 38.14a.84.84 0 01-.67.58h-.14a1.22 1.22 0 01-.68-.55 37.77 37.77 0 00-4.28-5.31l-1.93-2-6.41-6.65a54 54 0 01-3.84-3.94 1.3 1.3 0 00-.1-.15 3.84 3.84 0 01-.51-1v-.19a3.4 3.4 0 011-3c1.24-1.24 2.49-2.49 3.67-3.79 1.3 1.44 2.69 2.82 4.06 4.19a57.6 57.6 0 017.55 8.58A16 16 0 0135.65 34a14.55 14.55 0 01-.65 4.14z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </span>
{% endblock %}
```

Log :

```
Error : Class "Drupal\Core\Utility\Error" not found dans _drupal_error_handler_real() (/home/clients/bj764fgg66/sites/www.example.fr/core/includes/errors.inc ligne 63)
```

Comment: You'd need to include the log of the error.

Comment: @Kevin I just updated with the logs

Comment: Class "Drupal\Core\Utility\Error" is a separate, known, issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3258987 You will need a stack trace of the exception to determine the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the full error it is difficult to say, however, I think it is not possible to print expressions inside of `{% trans %}`. I think that you may be getting a Twig SyntaxError exception that reads:

> The text to be translated with "trans" can only contain references to simple variables.

So, surround only the text that needs translation with `{% trans %}`.